# TypeError: $ is not a function only on Firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a set of code to trigger sticky menu with opaque background which works fine on chrome except the Firefox. I don't know what could be the issue.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 60) {
        $('header div button').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('header div button').removeClass('menu-toggle');
    }
    else {
        $('header div button').removeClass('fixed-header');
        $('header div button').addClass('menu-toggle');
    }
});
```

function.php

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_nav', get_site_url() . '/wp-content/themes/app/js/nav.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
```

When I tried to look at console, it displays **TypeError: $ is not a function** which I have been trying to solve.

Thanks

Comment: Where is that jQuery located? Is it in a JS file? Do you define `$` first?

Comment: I have fixed the error. I wrapped it in jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   //
});

Comment: @disinfor Wordpress comes with JQuery installed.

Comment: Is jQuery maybe loading twice? Check the Network tab of chrome devtools

Comment: Yeah, it comes with jQuery installed, but you still need to define `$` - It should be `(function($){  //all your functions here })(jQuery)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the error. I wrapped it by wrapping the function in

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() { 
    // 
});
```

Though the error is still displaying "TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: If you've 'fixed' it but the error is still there then it's not really fixed, and this isn't an answer.

Comment: There is still some code that tries to reach $. You can solve it by adding the dollar sign like this:

`jQuery( document ).ready(function($) { // Your jQuery code here });`

Comment: @Sjors yeah, I fixed it ]. Thanks